# Disable "Summary" button from published page in Orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon

I wanna to remove or hide "Summary" button from the published page.So customer/visitor or whoever gotta go to insert and submit data to the form, can't go to summary page...

I referred the orbeon docs...specially "properties-local.xml" I can't find such a file in my directory..I run orbeon forms (community edition) with tomcat 7.0... Just i downloaded the zip official site, extracted it and copied and pasted "örbeon.war" file in to webapps forder in tomcat apache folder..Then I ran the orbeon forms on browser...But problem is that I mentioned earlier..

Please any one help me...

Answer (score 0):

For the location of the properties file, please refer to the [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties).

Your servlet container automatically expands the WAR file into a directory, but a better way is for you to do this yourself so that you know where the files are located, in particular properties-local.xml. See also [this](https://doc.orbeon.com/installation/tomcat#quick-setup).